# Caterpillar plot in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization

Is there a way to create a caterpillar plot in Python? It is possible to create it in SAS, but I can't seem to find a solution in any of Python's data visualization packages.

Comment: Please provide an example of data and an indication of the desired visualization.  Many variants on caterpillar plots exist.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/top-50-matplotlib-visualizations-the-master-plots-python/  Probably one of those can be altered to fit your needs (e.g. Dumbbell, Counts plot, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a dataframe `df` with columns `category`, `mean` and `std`. You want a line twice the `std`. The column `mean` is the center of this line.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.barh(df.category, tmp.fake_mean, xerr = tmp.fake_std, color="k", alpha=0.0, align='center', ecolor='r')
ax.plot()
```